# AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable??? What is wrong?

Tags: c#, android, android-manifest, monodevelop

Ok whenever i try to build my application i get the following warning which stops the application from building correctly and stops the Resource.designer.cs file from updating.

Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.

What can i do to fix this? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Are you running through the command line or the Eclipse GUI?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i'm running it in monodevelop.